# Fast way to solve a system of linear equations from Givens QR decomposition

Tags: matrices, factoring

I have this system of linear equations:

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ b= \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

I computed it's QR decomposition using Givens rotation matrices (pardon for the coefficients, I multiplied the matrices using MATLAB):

$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0.8944 & -0.2978 & -0.3332 \\ 0 & 0.7450 & -0.6660 \\ 0.4472 & 0.5957 & 0.6663 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ R = \begin{bmatrix} 2.2361 & 0.4472 & 1.3416 \\ 0 & 1.3407 & -0.4472 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.9992 \end{bmatrix} $$

Now the way that I use to compute the x vector is to calculate the inverse of Q, which is Q transposed, then calculate the inverse of R. This last thing implies a lot of computation. I would like to know if once that I have the QR factorization, there is a fast method to compute the x vector without computing any inverse matrix, for example using back-substitution.

Comment: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_lineqs_solving.html (see the heading "The QR decomposition of a matrix").

Comment: I don't understand. You already know about the back substitution, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "This last thing implies a lot of computation.".

No it doesn't. 
The way to solve $Rx=b$ is through backsubstitution. The last line gives you $0.9992x_3=3$. You get the value of $x_3$ then you you go to second last equation $1.3407x_2 -0.4472x_3=0$ You already know the value of $x_3$, you thus get the value of $x_2$ and you continue till you have everything. This is not more than a few lines of MATLAB code and is among the cheapest linear systems solve ever.

Comment: It's not Rx=b , it's Ax=b -> (QR)x = b, the problem is that I don't know how to apply back substitution when I have two matrices (Q and R).

Comment: \begin{align}Ax&=b\\QRx&=b\\Rx&=Q'b=\hat{b}\\Rx&=\hat{b}\end{align}

Comment: The final system $R x = Q' b$ is triangular and is efficient to solve as such

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve $Ax=b$ => $(QR)x=b$ since $A=QR$. => $Q'QRx=Q'b$ =>$Rx=Q'b$. simplify $Q'b$ and then equate $Rx$ to the result and use back substitution to find $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Explained using Math Cad example]
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This answer may be downvoted, since link only posts are discouraged here. But keep looking for questions to answer yourself.